# Expresión regular que no valida

Tags: java, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular para validar una frase que tiene dos condiciones:

- que empiece y termine en asterisco
- que tenga al menos un caracter

La expresión que he hecho es la siguiente:

```
\*\w|\s\*
```

La estoy probando en regex y me valida con la frase "hola que tal" (https://regexr.com/4r5ir)

Ahora bien, cuando quiero reproducirla en java, ésta parece que no funciona:

```
public static void main(String ... args)
{

    // Variables necesarias
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String frase;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^\*)(\w)|(\s)(\*$)*");
    Matcher m;

    // Solicitamos al usuario una frase, la misma debe empezar y terminar en * de lo contrario termina el programa
    System.out.println("Introduzca un texto entre asteriscos: ");
    frase = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(frase);

    m = p.matcher(frase);

    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Se cumple");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No se cumple");
    }

}
```

Con la frase `*hola que tal*`, el programa devuelve **No se cumple**.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En java el \ es un carácter de escape por lo tanto en tu expresión no incluye . Trata con:

```
    (^\\*)(\\w*)|(\\s*)(\\*$)*
```

Edición: faltan los asteriscos en \w y \s

Edició: esta expresión me funciono :

```
     (^\\*)(.*)(\\*$)
```

Comment: Esta también (^\\\*.*\\\*$)